# OpenVPN client connection reset, restarting [0]

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I'm trying to set up an OpenVPN server and use my client at my school which uses FortiGuard filtering services which is an extremely restrictive firewall. I have the server set up but the client keeps being disconnected and the server log says "Connection reset, restarting [0]"

server.conf
https://hasteb.in/raw/zihetawi

server log
https://hasteb.in/raw/uxeperuf

client.ovpn
https://hasteb.in/raw/roqamico

client log
https://hasteb.in/raw/ugonimeh

Any help is appreciated!